# JavaScript: do something while div.container < window.height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function `getRow()` that places an element inside `.container`. When the page loads, I want there to be enough elements to fill the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    while($('.container').height() < $(window).height()) {
            getRow();
    };
});
```

When I do this, the browser freezes and crashes. If I replace the `while` with an `if`, it places an element as intended (but just one of course).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly does getRow do?

Comment: @Andrew-II it gets something via ajax and does `.after()` to place it after `.row:last-child`

Comment: @user3733120: ajax? Do you realize it's (generally) asynchronous?

Comment: @Andrew-II Yes. Is that a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading your content with AJAX and it is asynchronous as zerkms noted, you should check your container's height after the AJAX request has been completed. Something like:

```
function getRow() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'your-url.php',
    success: function(response) {
      $('.row:last').after(response);
      checkHeight();
    }
  });
}

function checkHeight() {
  if ($('.container').height() < $(window).height()) {
    getRow();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkHeight();
});
```

EDIT: Since you are loading your content asynchronously you have to wait for the content to be loaded and appended to your DOM before you check the contents height again. If you perform the a while() loop before you will lock yourself on and endless loop and your asynchronous request will never be completed because you already freezed your browser.

Comment: Thanks a lot. When I do this, it seems to place the new element about 18 times (going way past the window size). It also doesn't seem to do the AJAX request again because the 18 elements are exactly the same (the `.php` if calls randomizes the element). Any idea about that?

Comment: Ah, it's because the images aren't loaded. I guess I'll have to delay it somehow.

Comment: @user3733120 Yes, the reason it goes beyond the windows size is because images aren't loaded yet. Images lodad is asynchronous too! And your AJAX call should be returning the same result on every request because the first one is cached and then your browser is loading the cached response I assume. You could try adding an unique parameter at the end of the URL like 'your.php?' + new Date().getTime() or something like that.